# A row was inserted unexpectedly on my MYSQL Table

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I have a problem inserting values on my table.

```
--------------------------------------------
|   products_id   |   related_products_ids |
| -----------------------------------------
|                |   1,2,3,4,6,            |
| -----------------------------------------
|    2            |   1,2,3,6,             |
| -----------------------------------------
|    3            |   1,2,4,               |
-------------------------------------------
```

There is a blank `products_id` value where all inserted values on each product ids are on its `related_products_ids` value.

I use this code,

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['rp_product']);$i++) {
    $check_val .= $_POST['rp_product'][$i];
    $check_val .=","; 
}

$insert_rp_ids1 = explode(',', $check_val);

foreach($insert_rp_ids1 as $rp_ids) {

    $related_query = "SELECT related_products_ids, products_id 
                      FROM ".TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS." 
                      WHERE products_id = '" . $rp_ids ."'";

    $result_rp = mysql_query($related_query);
    $related_products_value = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_rp);

    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT products_id FROM ".TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS." WHERE products_id = '$rp_ids'"))){

        $rp_values = $related_products_value['related_products_ids'].$products_id.',';
        $rps_each1 = array('related_products_ids' => $rp_values);

        $wpdb->update( TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS, $rps_each1, array( 'products_id' => $rp_ids ));

     } else {

         $rps_each2 = array('products_id' => $rp_ids,
                   'related_products_ids' => $products_id.',');

         $wpdb->insert(TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS, $rps_each2);
     }
 }
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I can't find it. That row is not necessary and its no use.

Please help.

Comment: Could you reformat your code using spaces/tabs to make it easier to read? At the moment it's like reading a body of text without paragraphs.

Comment: Lol, spaces for indentation ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a mess but this should avoid problems in future..

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['rp_product']); $i++)
{
  $check_val1 .= $_POST['rp_product'][$i] .","; //gather data
}
$check_val = trim($check_val1, ',');  //clean last ,
unset($check_val1); //flush

$insert_rp_ids1 = explode(',', $check_val);

foreach($insert_rp_ids1 as $rp_ids)
{

 if($result_rp = mysql_query("SELECT related_products_ids, products_id FROM ".TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS." where products_id = '" . $rp_ids ."'"))
 {
    if($products_id > 0)
   {
  $related_products_value = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_rp);
  $rp_values = $related_products_value['related_products_ids'] . "," . $products_id;

  $rps_each1 = array('related_products_ids' => $rp_values);
  $wpdb->update( TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS, $rps_each1, array( 'products_id' => $rp_ids ));
   }
  }
  else
  {
   if($rp_ids > 0 && $products_id > 0)
   {
   $rps_each2 = array('products_id' => $rp_ids, 'related_products_ids' => $products_id);
   $wpdb->insert(TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS, $rps_each2);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I have modified a bit of your code to do its job. Thanks Xfile.

Answer (score 0):

I see this in perl on array initialization.  When you initialize an array, sometimes it is created with a null zeroeth element, depending on how the array is declared.

Try either run through with the perl debugger (perl -D) and check the insert array, or include Data::Dumper and print the whole array.